# How can I get the locale of Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, parsley.js

While defining Parsley's locale **in the backend** like this:

```
Parsley.setLocale('de');
```

How can I get the locale value ('de' for example) **in the front-end** using javascript/jquery?

I tried a function like getLocale()... but it doesn't seems to work.

NOTE: I dont have access to the backend.

Comment: What do you mean, defining the locale in the backend? Parsley works in the frontend. There's no getter.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/fr.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/it.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('fr');
</script>
```

[Source](http://chronogram.co/js/jquery.parsley/doc/index.html)